# Need Shell script to monitor files on remote SUSE dir ApmPerfMonitor ApmPerfMonitor

Tags: file, shell, monitor

We
would need monitoring on below folder for respective directories & sub directories to see if the files in the directory are greater than 100 files. Also none of the file should sit more than 4 hrs.

If files in the directory is more than 100 we would need an alert. Not sure why this script is working. Could you please confirm?

```
Path – /export/ftpaccounts/image-processor/working/
```

The Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOCKFILE=/tmp/findimages.lock

if [ -f ${LOCKFILE} ]; then
    exit 0
fi

touch ${LOCKFILE}

NUM=`find /mftstaging/vim/inbound/active \
-ignore_readdir_race -depth -type f -m min +60 -print | 
xargs wc -l`

if [[ ${NUM:0:1} -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "${NUM:0:1} files older than 60minutes" | 
    mail -s "batch import is slow" ${MAILTO}
fi

rm -rf  ${LOCKFILE}
```

Answer (score 0):

The format of your original post made it difficult to tell what you were trying to accomplish. If I understand you just want to find the number of files in the remote directory that are greater than 60 minutes old, then with a couple of changes your script should work fine. Try:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOCKFILE=/tmp/findimages.lock
ACTIVE=/mftstaging/vim/inbound/active

[ -f ${LOCKFILE} ] && exit 0

touch ${LOCKFILE}

# NUM=`find /mftstaging/vim/inbound/active \
# -ignore_readdir_race -depth -type f -m min +60 -print | 
# xargs wc -l`

NUM=$(find $ACTIVE -type f -mmin +60 | wc -l)

## if [ $NUM -gt 100 ]; then  # if you are test for more than 100
if [ $NUM -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "$NUM files older than 60minutes" | 
    mail -s "batch import is slow" ${MAILTO}
fi

rm -rf  ${LOCKFILE}
```

**Note:** you will want to implement some logic that deals with a stale lock file, and perhaps use `trap` to insure the lock is removed regardless of how the script terminates. e.g.:

```
trap 'rm -rf ${LOCKFILE}' SIGTERM SIGINT EXIT
```